# Unable to find element using protactor which have same classes

Tags: selenium, protractor, element

I have one check box and two links with same classes & same Div.During the automation testing using protractor, i want to click on check box but it click on Links.
i am writing this code but its not  working, please provide a solution.
Code:

```
element(by.id('Remember')).click();
```

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6rXJ.jpg)

please find HTMl code:-

```
<div class="input-field">
            <div class="pas_rembr">
              <input name="remember" id="Remember" class="css-checkbox ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-model="rememberMe" type="checkbox" ng-required="true" required="required">
              <!-- <label for="Remember" class="css-label">I agree with the <a class="text_link" target="_blank" ng-href="{{baseUrl}}terms-conditions">Terms & Conditions</a>.</label> -->
              <label for="Remember" class="css-label">I have read and I agree with <a class="text_link" target="_blank" ng-href="/lmd/terms-conditions" href="/lmd/terms-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a> and the <a class="text_link" target="_blank" ng-href="/lmd/privacy" href="/lmd/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> of this site.</label>
            </div>
            <span class="errorForm ng-hide" ng-show="(memberForm.remember.$dirty || submitted) &amp;&amp; ((memberForm.remember.$error.required))">
              <span class="errorForm ng-scope ng-hide" ng-show="memberForm.remember.$error.required" translate="TERAMS_CONDITION_IS_REQUIRED">Terms and condition is required</span>
            </span>
          </div>
```

Comment: You need to mention Error description which you are getting, Also instead of HTML link you need to include sample block of HTML code, Link will be remove for future user.

Comment: Thanks @SanjaPaskova error is not  coming but it click on other link instead of  check box. please see attched image.

Comment: If you hover over the `INPUT` for the checkbox in the dev tools window, what is highlighted on the browser page? I'm guessing the hitbox for that element is really large or something else odd is going on. A link to the page would likely clear this up.

Comment: does element(by.Id('Remember')).element(by.className('css-checkbox')).click(); help?

Comment: not working, how? Still clicks on the wrong thing, or complains it cannot click at all. Is this a site we could look at ourselves, or it is proprietary?

Comment: one kind of different idea would be as follows. Protractor will click at the middle of an element. In your case those links are in there and getting clicked. Instead, you could use getLocation on the element to finds its x and y, hen build up a click on a location that is at x and y+half the height (from getSize, so at the extreme left). Or if you want to have some fun, take the coordinates of the hrefs (get both elements), and click at the midpoint of the top right of the the first and bottom left of the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var el = element(by.css('label[for="Remember"]'));
browser.actions().mouseMove(el, {x: 20, y: 3}).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

For your tests, the CSS selector would be

```
element = $$('label.css-label > a:nth-child(2)');
```

This should be able to click on the second `a` child of the label element.